# set-wallpaper contract

Tags: wallpaper, contract

when using set-wallpaper (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/io.elementary.contract.set-wallpaper) as sudo, it tries to recursively delete everything starting from the directory where the file is located, and only stops (thankfully) because i have a non-empty dir in the same dir as the wallpaper. Running as current user works fine.

Comment: Can I ask why would you run it as sudo?

Comment: It runs from another script which needs to be run as sudo. However, i've just added my own check to make sure the env variable "XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR" is not empty before running set-wallpaper. I also added a "su -u $USER ..." to the command and it seems to work. I've submitted a bug report to elemntaryOS.